# How to get probability and label prediction at the same time using sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have a multiclass classifier and I need to get the probability and label at the same time.

`model.predict_proba(X)` returns the probabilities for all trained classes for each data point.

`model.predict(X)` returns the label  for each data point.

I don't want to predict twice each data point.

Comment: You could just use the probability predicted by predict_proba.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use `predict_proba` and then to get the label use `np.argmax`:

```
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
x = dataset[['pollution', 'dew', 'temp', 'press', 'wnd_spd', 'snow']].values
y = dataset[['wnd_dir']].values
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

cls = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
cls.fit(x, y)

z = cls.predict_proba(x)
labels = np.argmax(z, axis=1)
classes = cls.classes_
labels = [classes[i] for i in labels]
print(accuracy_score(y, labels))
```

Comment: Would be nice if this were built into scikit learn estimators. Else pipelines need to be manually wrapped.

Comment: If you add `probs = np.max(z, axis=1)` to the above code, you get the probablity of the max scoring `label` for each example in the input.

Comment: @BikashGyawali it's already there!